# Unable to boot after install on i386 platform, missing grub, black screen

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, grub

I'm having a hard time starting with elementary OS.

After managing to install it from a USBKey (0.3.2 32bit version) on an old ACER AspireOne, erasing pre-existing system, I find myself unable to boot it. (I needed 3 attempts as I got twice a weird error of the installer being unable to write file, saying my hardrive must have a problem. In the end selecting the simplest options worked - no encryption, no update during install, no 3rd parties)

I first had to figure how to get a GRUB config ([How can I fix a secure boot failing to grub when I installed 0.3.1?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1)) but to no avail as I had no `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Booting from USB key and installing boot-repair helped me get a grub config ([A fresh install boots to the grub command prompt](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2480/a-fresh-install-boots-to-the-grub-xommand-prompt)). I now get a grub menu to choose from, but it unfortunately boots to a black screen.
In desperation I've tried to add `nomodeset` to the command in grub ([Black Screen after GRUB (Windows 8.1 dualboot)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/911/black-screen-after-grub-windows-8-1-dualboot)) but it didn't help.

Note that I have a weird message `error: attempt to read or write outside of 'hd0'` appearing before the grub menu and after the selection, just before the screen turn black.

I might be a bit unfortunate, but I was hopeful that choosing the simplest setup (full new install, single OS, no secure boot problem) would be straightforward.

Comment: hum, too bad nobody has a clue, I guess I'll need to wait for 0.4 to test it again...

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue because elementary os have little bug in installing grub without internet.

When i connect to internet and installing again grub install properly.

May you have same issue, try to install it with internet connection